# how to set image width for responsive image slider using JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make responsive image slider for my website using Jquery and Javascript.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="#" alt="Slider Image" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="#" alt="Slider Image" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="#" alt="Slider Image" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My question is how to set the image `width`.
I set image `width` for `100%` and `height` for `auto`.

I set div `width` for `100%`, but when I resize the screen, the image is not responsive.

I want to learn from scratch instead using plugins possible.
How can I solve this problems?

Comment: Is the image set as a background or as a stand alone image?

Comment: It would help us out a lot if you could post a code and jsfiddle with what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by simply setting in your CSS something like this:

```css
img {
  display:block /*fix inline gap - optional*/
  max-width:100%; /* the trick is here - setting max-width instead of width */
  height:auto;
}
```

**See snippet below with your code:**

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/*demo styles*/

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900/sports" alt="Slider Image" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900/city" alt="Slider Image" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900/food" alt="Slider Image" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

no need to use jQuery/JavaScript

Comment: These images are photos, not background. Could you give me your fiddle address again? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bro ,my advice to you is to use the plugin called bxSlider ( fully responsive ) slider. Easy for use and easy understandable.You can set modes, make adaptiveHeight...and much more options I personally was trying to make my own slide , after hours of a lot nervous I've decided to use that plugin. [click here for downloading bxSlider !](http://bxslider.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle of what you are looking for - assuming it's not a background image.

[https://jsfiddle.net/WebDevelopWolf/u6vompp2/](http://Image%20Fiddle)

Basically, the code you need to make your images responsive is:

```
img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

If it's a background image though then the you'll need:

```
div {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background:url('http://www.abstract-thinking.co.uk/img/logo.jpg')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because you haven't given a `width` and `height` for your image

so for your `div`, you have given `width:100%` and `height:auto`, (if you want you can give any `px` or `%` value for your `div`)

then for your image inside the `div` give `width` and `height` for it
(`div img` says `images` inside the `div` tag)

```
div img{
 width:100%;
 height:100%
}
```

in here, child element takes the full widh and height of it's parent element.hope this will help to you.